# Facebook like button count inconsistancy due to automatic url rewriting

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite, best-practice, social-buttons, facebook

I was trying to add the facebook like button to my product pages but then I noticed that the like counter has different numbers depending on where the page was accessed from and the URL it has.

Magento by default creates 3 URL rewrites for each new product automatically.

- If I access a product from my home page it has the URL  `mysite/product-name.html`.
- If I access a product from a base category it has the URL `mysite/base-category/product-name.html`
- If I access a product from a sub-category it has the URL `mysite/base-category/sub-category/product-name.html`

all of the above have different like counts and are treated as different pages. is there a way to merge the like counts while still keeping the SEO friendly URLs? what are the best practices in this regard?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the canonical meta tags did not solve the issue like I initially thought they did.

I ended up solving this issue by creating a helper function that query the url rewrite collection for a product id and then retrieves the product url with the deepest category levels (the url with the most '/').
and then I used this helper to get the product url for the social buttons, and I used it for the item link in list.phtml and new.phtml.

so now all my links refer to a single rewrite.

I don't know if this is the best solution but it does the job for me at least for now.

Helper code:

```
public static function getFullProductUrl(
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
) {
$url = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->getCollection()
->addFilter('is_system', '1')
->addFilter('product_id', $product->getId())
->addFilter('store_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->addFieldToFilter('category_id', array('gt' => '0'));
$items = $url->getItems();
$count = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $sc = substr_count($item->getRequestPath(),'/');
    if ($sc > $count){
        $count = $sc;
        $which = $item;
    }
}
if (!$which->getRequestPath()) {
return $product->getUrlPath();
}
return Mage::getBaseUrl() . $which->getRequestPath();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess using canonical meta tags to link the pages with each other will solve the issue. To enable them, Login to admin, go to `System > Configuration > Catalog` and then click on the option labelled "Search Engine Optimizations". Enable for products or categories accordingly.

Comment: hi thank you for the answer. sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. I am still testing it out to see if it actually fixed the issue. I won't forget to accept this answer if it works. :)

Comment: Ok I finished testing it and it seems to work but I noticed something strange about it's behavior and I was hoping you could explain it. when I access some links through my homepage the breadcrumbs at the top display this path: `home>product-name` but after entering the product page from it's sub-category the breadcrumbs display `home>base-category>sub-category>product-name` throughout the site and no matter where I access the page from. is it due to caching?

Comment: this is a default behavior, direct accessing of product will only show `home > product` while accessing the product through categories will include them in breadcrumb as well.

Comment: that's true but at the moment after activating the canonical meta tags, when I access the products from my home page the breadcrumbs show `home > base-category > sub-category > product`

Comment: probably due to cache

Answer (score 1):

You can also set product url to NOT include category path in `admin > system > configuration > catalog > seo` area.

Comment: The problem is that I wanted to preserve the categories in the path.